# Nested and non-nested cross validation exactly the same for different ML techniques

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using K-fold CV (nested vs non-nested) to figure out whether my classification model is over fitting the data.

The code used essentially is the same as taken from sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

Due to the way that nested and non-nested CV partitions the data randomly I'd expect that the non-nested CV would be different from the nested CV for example:

[image: Random Forest non-nested vs nested CV]

But for KNN, Logistic Regression and Multilayer Perceptron classifiers the results for non-nested and nested cross validation are exactly the same over 25 trials.

[image: KNN non-nested vs nested CV]
[image: LR non-nested vs nested CV]
[image: MLP non-nested vs nested CV]

Anyone help explain the results or tell me what I may be doing wrong? Thanks!

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

def CVNCV_organiser(classifier, p_grid, nnscorelist, nscorelist, i):
    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    nn_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    nn_clf.fit(X, y)
    nnscorelist[i] = nn_clf.best_score_
    
    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    scores = cross_validate(nn_clf, X, y, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True)
    nscorelist.append(scores)
    #nested_scores = cross_val_score(nn_clf, X, y, cv=outer_cv)
    #nscorelist[i] = nested_scores.mean()
    
    
def diff_plot(str_name_clf, nested_scoring, non_nested_scoring): 
    
    score_diff = non_nested_scoring - nested_scoring
    print("Average difference of {:6f} with std. dev. of {:6f}."
          .format(score_diff.mean(), score_diff.std()))

    # Plot scores on each trial for nested and non-nested CV
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(211)
    non_nested_scores_line, = plt.plot(non_nested_scoring, color='r')
    nested_line, = plt.plot(nested_scoring, color='b')
    plt.ylabel("score", fontsize="14")
    plt.legend([non_nested_scores_line, nested_line],
               ["Non-Nested CV", "Nested CV"],
               bbox_to_anchor=(0, .4, .5, 0))
    plt.title(f"{str_name_clf} Non-Nested and Nested Cross Validation",
              x=.5, y=1.1, fontsize="15")

    # Plot bar chart of the difference.
    plt.subplot(212)
    difference_plot = plt.bar(range(trials), score_diff)
    plt.xlabel("Trial number")
    plt.legend([difference_plot],
               ["Non-Nested CV - Nested CV Score"],
               bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1, .8, 0))
    plt.ylabel("score difference", fontsize="14")

    plt.show()


trials = 25
hparams_MLP = {'model__activation': ['identity'],
              'model__solver': ['sgd'],
              'model__learning_rate': ['constant'],
              'model__hidden_layer_sizes': [(21,17)],
              'model__tol': [0.00034]}

scoring = ['accuracy', 'balanced_accuracy', 'f1_macro', 'precision', 'recall', 'roc_auc']

MLP_non_nested_scores = np.zeros(trials)
MLP_nested_scores = np.zeros(trials)
MLP_nested_scoring = []


for i in range(trials):
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    CVNCV_organiser(MLP_clf_pipeline, hparams_MLP, MLP_non_nested_scores, MLP_nested_scoring, i)
    
    MLP_nested_scores[i] = MLP_nested_scoring[i]['test_accuracy'].mean()

    
diff_plot('MLP', MLP_nested_scores, MLP_non_nested_scores)
```

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without code, you say it's essentially the same as the example but presumably, there's some difference, and if you're doing something wrong it can only be in the code.

Comment: Also have you tried the original example unchanged? I noticed that despite using two cv's they're both initialised with the same seed (the loop counter)? So both should return the same splits on each iteration?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth I've included the code for one of the models thank you!

Comment: Its not clear to me what's going on, but first thing I'd investigate is if it's related to the fact that your doing a grid search but your 'grid' only has one choice per parameter, so `GridSearchCV` is probably doing the exact same thing as `cross_validate` (since they're also initialised with the same random_state